# commit after select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, commit

I have read the explanations when a `commit` may be neccessary after a `select` statement for DB2 and MySQL:

[Is a commit needed on a select query in DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521475/is-a-commit-needed-on-a-select-query-in-db2)

[Should I commit after a single select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287749/should-i-commit-after-a-single-select)

My question is when and why would it be important to `commit` after executing a `select` statement using Oracle?

Comment: I am no Oracle pro, so perhaps someone more knowledgeable can comment on this, but I have run scripts that have executed a large number of large select statements, which eventually returned database server temp space issues.  Committing after each select eliminated this.

Answer (score 15):

If you did a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;` you would need a COMMIT or ROLLBACK to release the records held for update.  Otherwise, I can't think of any reason to do this.

Answer (score 15):

there are only a  few situations that I can think of that you may want to commit after a select.

1. if your select is joining on database links, a transaction will be created. if you attempt to close this link, you'd get an error unless you committed/rolled back the transaction.
2. select for update (as DCookie says) to release the locks.
3. to remove an serialized isolation level if set or to add one, if you've been selecting from db links prior to invoking this.