# Python SQLite: Is Commit() needed for SELECT Queries?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have made it a habbit that when i do `cur.execute()` functions, I do a `sql.commit()` function right after.

Is `sql.commit()` needed if I do not modify the database (i.e. only do a `SELECT` query)?

Here is an example:

```
sql = sqlite3.connect('DB.db')
cur = sql.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM table')
sql.commit()
```

Comment: If it a simple select statement like in your example, there is no reason to perform a commit.

Comment: Actually, this might help provide more context. Let me know if this was helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430424/commit-after-select

Comment: My select queries are simple and do not modify the database. They just pull info.

Comment: The example in the docs implies you can use execute:

c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python does not begin a transaction for select statements.

From the [Transaction control](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions) section of the sqlite3 module docs:

> By default, the sqlite3 module opens transactions implicitly before a Data Modification Language (DML) statement (i.e. INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/REPLACE), and commits transactions implicitly before a non-DML, non-query statement (i. e. anything other than SELECT or the aforementioned).

Comment: (since english is not my mother tongue, I'm confused by the latter part of this doc) does `and commits transactions implicitly before a non-DML, non-query statement` means sqlite3 will implicitly do commits for both non-DML (insert/delete/update/create) and non-query (anything other than select) ?